# Sets (arrays of heterogeneous types) in C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I would like to simulate python sets in C++.
According to the [faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#heterogeneous-containers), an idiomatic way to do this would be to use an `std::vector` which stores pointers (better if smart pointers) to a handle class which is then overloaded by the specific types which we would like to store in the simulated set.

This is my attempt:

```cpp
// experimenting with vectors of heterogeneous elements (like sets in python)
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


// Handle can wrap an int, a double, or a string.
class Handle {
public:
  Handle();
  virtual int val();
  virtual double val();
  virtual std::string val();
};


class Int : public Handle {
public:
  Int(const int n) : value(n) {};
  int val() override { return value; };
private:
  int value;
};


class Double : public Handle {
public:
  Double(const double n) : value(n) {};
  double val() override { return value; };
private:
  double value;
};


class String : public Handle {
public:
  String(const std::string& n) : value(n) {};
  std::string val() override { return value; };
private:
  std::string value;
};


int main() {
  // v simulates a set with 12 elements of types int, double, or string.
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Handle>> v(12);

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i += 3) {
    v[i] = std::shared_ptr<Int>(new Int(i));
    v[i + 1] = std::shared_ptr<Double>(new Double(i + 1.));
    v[i + 2] = std::shared_ptr<String>(new String(std::to_string(i + 2)));
  }

  for (auto& it : v) {
    std::cout << it->val() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This approach would be preferable to declaring `v` as an `std::vector<Handle*>`, because using smart pointers would allow me to forget about deleting manually the pointers, while at the same time achieving runtime polymorphism.

The code above however does not compile, because we are not allowed to overload a function (`val()` in this case) only on the return types.

Is there a way to fix my code so that I can simulate a set with different types? Is there a better, idiomatic way to do it?

## Edit

Here's how I changed my code after n. 'pronouns' m.'s answer.
The code seems to work, and I am happy with it as an exercise in using inheritance and smart pointers (even though it's not the best solution for the specific problem at hand, see Maxim Egorushkin's answer for a much better approach).

```cpp
// experimenting with vectors of heterogeneous elements (like sets in python)
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


// Handle can wrap an int, a double, or a string.
class Handle {
public:
  Handle() {};
  virtual void print(std::ostream&) = 0;
};


class Int : public Handle {
public:
  Int(const int n) : value(n) {};
  void print(std::ostream& s) override { s << value << std::endl; };
private:
  int value;
};


class Double : public Handle {
public:
  Double(const double n) : value(n) {};
  void print(std::ostream& s) override { s << value << std::endl; };
private:
  double value;
};


class String : public Handle {
public:
  String(const std::string& n) : value(n) {};
  void print(std::ostream& s) override { s << value << std::endl; };
private:
  std::string value;
};


int main() {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Handle>> v(12);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i += 3) {
    v[i] = std::shared_ptr<Int>(new Int(i));
    v[i + 1] = std::shared_ptr<Double>(new Double(i + 1.));
    v[i + 2] = std::shared_ptr<String>(new String(std::to_string(i + 2)));
  }

  for (const auto& it : v) {
    it->print(std::cout);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with your code is, that the compiler cannot know at compile-time which return value `val` has, so how should it provide the right overloade for `<<` to use? You could try it with the visitor idiom.

Comment: Writing Python in C++ syntax is going to be a frustrating experience. Not recommended.

Comment: A terminology note. Overloading andoverriding are two very different things. It is the former you are trying to use.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I certainly do not want to write Python in C++, but I thought trying to implement a container with heterogeneous types would be a good exercise to learn some C++ (in particular, how to use runtime polymorphism in an idiomatic way).
As for your second comment: thanks, I will check out the difference. Should I remove the override keyword?

Comment: Uh-oh, an editing glitch. You are trying to *override*, not overload.

Comment: "Should I remove the override keyword?" The technique doesn't work at all. Removing the keyword makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is a **statically typed** language. Every expression has a statically-determined type. This means you, tge compiler, and everybody else are able to determine the type from the program text alone, without trying to execute any code.

(An object denoted by tge expression may also have a dynamic type, determined at run time, but this is not what we are concerned with). A

Let's look at this expression.

```
it->val()
```

What is its type?

The only possible answer is `std::string`. Indeed, the type of `it` is `std::shared_ptr<Handle>`, and `Handle::val` is specified to return `std::string`. The fact `Handle` has derived types plays no role. Whatever the *dynamic* type of the pointed-to object is, the *static* type of `it->val()` is `std::string`, and if something has static type of `std::string`, it cannot have dynamic type of say `double`. This is the reason why you cannot override `val` this way.

So what should we do if we want to print different things depending on the dynamic type of the object?

The standard OOP solution is to have a method that *prints*, as oposed to a method that returns a thing to be printed. In C++ terms that would be a virtual function, e.g.

```
virtual void print() = 0;
```

overriden in each derived class.

Of course the real life isn't that simple. What if we need to print to an arbitrary stream? We need to pass a stream as an argument to `print`. Perhaps we need to.pass some more stuff. Maybe we want to specify a printed field width, or precision, or whatever. What if we want to do a bunch of other stuff besides printing?  Do we need a separate method for each thing we want to do? OOP studies answers to these and more questions, but I cannot answer them in a single SO post :(

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to simulate python sets in C++. According to the faq, an idiomatic way to do this would be to use an `std::vector` which stores pointers...

Sets in C++ are [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (often a red-black tree) and [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) (a hash table). `std::vector` is a resizable array.

If you know all the types you are going to store in the set, use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) for value, not pointers.

E.g.:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using Value = std::variant<int, double, std::string>;
    using ValueSet = std::unordered_set<Value>;

    ValueSet s;
    s.insert(1);       // int
    s.insert(3.14);    // double
    s.insert("hello"); // string

    for(auto const& value : s)
        visit([](auto&& v) { std::cout << v << '\n'; }, value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I see that your solution is clearly better than my attempt for building an heterogeneous container, but what if I wanted anyway to use an std::vector of shared pointers to a handle class? Surely this is not the best thing to do here, but it could be interesting for learning C++.

Comment: @J.D. You have a choice of `std::variant`, `std::any`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` for values. For the container, you can use pretty much [any standard container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). My example shows usage of `std::variant`, which I recommend over the alternatives, if possible.